# Removing lines in overlapping triangles in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

perhaps my method of trying to get the figure I want is very naive and simplistic- but I am very new to Tikz and can't do much else.
I need to obtain a figure similar to the one on the left (with the final aim of getting the figure on the right). 
[image]

I do get the  following at the moment but don't know how to get rid of unnecessary lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--(4,5) -- (1,0)--(0,0) ;
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.5,0)}]
    \draw (1,0)--(4,5) -- (2,0)--(1,0) ;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[shift={(-1.5,0)}]

   \draw (2,0)--(4,5) -- (3,0)--(2,0) ;
   \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.5,0)}]
   \draw (3,0)--(4,5) -- (4,0)--(3,0) ;
   \end{scope}

  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! If one can help with the final part too that'd be absolutely amazing :)

Comment: What are the unnecessary lines? Draw them in colour so that your problem is easily understood.

Comment: If I knew the coordinates to draw it in colour the problem would have been nearly solved ! I just need the triangle in the middle to stand out and the support of the long "tree". Zarko seems to have provided a solution, though I wonder if there is a way to just remove the lines instead. But I guess its not practical.

Comment: You can color your figure with GIMP if you don't know how to do it with LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

first is defined paths used to determine intersections points then are drawn line between given coordinates and calculated intersections.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[name path=A] (0,0)--(4,5) -- (1,0);
    \path[name path=B] (0.5,0)--(4.5,5) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw[name intersections={of=A and B, by={s1}}]
        (0,0) -- (4,5) -- (s1) -- (4.5,5) -- (1.5,0) -- cycle;
%
    \path[name path=C] (0.5,0)--(2.5,5) -- (1.5,0);
    \path[name path=D] (1.0,0)--(2.0,5) -- (2.0,0);
  \draw[name intersections={of=C and D, by={s2,s3,s4}},red]
        (0.5,0) -- (s2) -- (2,5) -- (s3) -- (2.5,5) -- (s4) -- (2.0,0) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I made it in the end, though it took me soooo long to get it done!